# Cruise Control .NET configuration : can a project launch another project?

Tags: continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

Let's say I have defined n projects and I want to have a last one to launch, in a defined order, the n first ones.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, the CC.NET website was down, but it's up now and I found the answer :

http://ccnet.sourceforge.net/CCNET/ForceBuildPublisher.html

```
<publishers>
    <forcebuild>
        <project>AcceptanceTestProject</project>
        <serverUri>tcp://buildserver2:21234/CruiseManager.rem</serverUri>
    </forcebuild>
</publishers>
```